# Changing email address every time in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I need some good suggestions for my query. Actually i am writing the automation test suit for my integration environment using selenium cucumber. When i enter an email address and proceed to complete the process, then that email address will be stored in the database. So, i can't use the same address for next time in the next scenario, because it is already stored in database and its saying that you are already a user. Now i am changing email addresses before running my test suit manually. It is not a good approach because i need a full automation test suit. How to create a dynamic way to enter new email id automatically every time?

Answer (score 1):

we can use random function to generate a email id everytime as we go. Below code might give you some idea.

```
String userName = ""+(int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE);
String emailID = "User"+userName+"@example.com";
```

**Note:** I have purposefully used the "User" as prefix to the username so that after a point of time we can delete this email id's starting with "User" from db if needed.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: it seems really very helpful. Let me try this and will let you know. Thanks bro

Comment: Error:(10, 27) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way:

First of all: create a copy of your clean database with test values

1. Revert the database to the copy that you have
2. Deploy the application
3. Run your unit tests

Because you are reverting the database, any changes made by unit testing will be undone.

Comment: Actually i cant revert the services because i am getting the response from real server not the mock.

Comment: @user2357662 Then you should go with Santhosh's answer. But you should really run your tests in a different environment than the real server, that way you know something is broken BEFORE the user can experience it.

Comment: Yes i have test suits for the dev and test environments but before deploying to production i need to test the integration environment completely (manually).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code. Hope, it will help you.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id of the element").SendKeys("Automation_" + Number.Next(1, 1000).ToString() + "_" + driver.RandomString(4) + "@gmail.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a function for generating a random email and storing that random email on a text file. Now when the sign in happens, I am asking my code to read the file that has the email id, and store the email in a variable and pass it as `send_keys(variable_name)`

In this case, I am avoiding random_email to be called each time, and since the file will get overwritten each time, for a session, u always can have one random email id.

Answer (score 0):

I would have my scenario clean the database before entering a well known e-mail address. This would remove the problem of creating a new e-mail address every time and introduce predictability into the process.

Trouble shooting something that has an element of randomness is something I would prefer to avoid at almost any cost.